# get interval ID from else statement when set in IF

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, responsive-design

I am attempting to create a responsive slider, that will change to a simple set of dot points when in mobile mode (`< 940`).

The issue I am facing is in my else statement I am unable to clearintervals that were made in the if statement, because t comes up as undefined. I have resorted to using

`for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++) window.clearInterval(i);` to clear the interval which works, but I don't like it because it's ugly and cumbersome, is there another way of accomplishing this?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    function rePosition() {

        //get responsive width
        var container_width = $('.container').width();

        //Slider for desktops only
        if(container_width >= 940) {

            //get variables
            var slide_width = $('.slider_container').width();
            var number_of_slides = $('.slider_container .slide').length;
            var slider_width = slide_width*number_of_slides;

            //set element dimensions
            $('.slide').width(slide_width);
            $('.slider').width(slider_width);

            var n = 1;
            var t = 0;
            $('.slider_container').hover(function() { 
                clearInterval(t);
                }, function() {
                t = setInterval(sliderLoop,6000);
            });

            var marginSize = i = 1;

            //Called in Doc Load
            function sliderLoop(trans_speed) {

                if (trans_speed) {
                    var trans_speed = trans_speed;
                }
                else
                {
                    var trans_speed = 3000;
                }

                if (i < number_of_slides) {
                    marginSize = -(slide_width * i++);
                }
                else
                {
                    marginSize = i = 1;
                }

                $('.slider').animate({ marginLeft: marginSize }, trans_speed);  
            }

            t = setInterval(sliderLoop,6000);

            $('.items li').hover(function() {
                $('.slider').stop();
                clearInterval(t);
                var item_numb = $(this).index();
                i = item_numb;
                sliderLoop(500);
            }, function() {
                t = setInterval(sliderLoop,6000);
            });

        }
        else
        {

            for (var i = 1; i < 99999; i++)
            window.clearInterval(i);
            $('.slider').stop(true, true);
            $('.slider').css('margin-left', '0px');

            //rearrange content
            if($('.slider .slide .slide_title').length < 1) {
                $('.items ul li').each(function() {
                    var item_numb = $(this).index();
                    var content = $(this).text();
                    $('.slider .slide:eq(' + item_numb + ')').prepend('<div class="title slide_title">' + content + '</div>')
                });
            }
        }

    }

    rePosition();

    $(window).resize(function() {
      rePosition();
    });

});
```

Comment: Put you interval ids to an array, and iterate through the array.

Comment: @Teemu I posted code with your solution. If you want to copy it and post it yourself, go for it and I'll delete my post.

Comment: @m59 No, no, please don't delete your post, it's OK this way.

Answer (score 2):

Teemu's comment is correct. I'll expand on it. Make an array available to all of the relevant code (just remember that globals are bad).

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var myIntervalArray = [];
```

Now, whenever you create an interval you will need to reference later, do this:

```
var t = setInterval();//etc
myIntervalArray.push(t); //or just put the interval directly in.
```

Then to clear them, just loop the array and clear each interval.

```
for (var i=0; i<myIntervalArray.length; i++)
  clearInterval(myIntervalArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm, wouldn't t only be defined when the if part ran... as far as I can tell, this is going to run and be done... the scope will be destroyed. If you need to maintain the scope across calls, you'll need to move your var statements outside of reposition(), like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var t = 0;
    ...

    function rePosition() { ... }
});
```